# i have two client projects, is it possible to create two separate partitions for two client projects in same VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services

hi guys i have two client projects and have a single account, is it possible to accustom those two projects separately in a single account without the projects being overlaped

Answer (score 3):

Why would you? A single account can have many separate vpc's at no extra cost, and if you goal is a nice clean/secure separation between the two clients, give them each their own VPC.

Comment: Agreed, though @younus watch out for account limits. Initial limit is 5 VPCs per region so be prepared to request a limit increase.